# Как сделать программную прокрутку ScrollView?(switUI)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Необходимо реализовать программную прокрутку ScrollView при нажатии на кнопку, как в яндекс еде.  Как примерно это можно сделать? И как можно узнать состояние ScrollView(его размер, местоположение пользователя в ScrollView).
Или для такого функционала нужно использовать другой инструмент?

```
ScrollView {
           ForEach(0..<buttons.count) { i in
                    FlowStack(category: buttons[i], products: products[i])
                }.padding(8)
            }
```

Body тело структуры FlowStak:

```
var body: some View {
    
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Text(category)
            .bold()
            .padding()
            .foregroundColor(colorCategoryList)
            .font(Font.system(size: 40))
            
        ForEach(0..<self.getNumberOfRows()) { row in
            HStack {
                ForEach(0..<self.getNumberOfColumns(row: row)) { col in
                    ProductCard(product: products[row * 2 + col])
                }.padding(8)
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Мне кажется лучше описать тут, что именно вы хотите, так как не все пользуются Яндекс Едой.

Comment: Нашел решение моей задачи, https://ichi.pro/ru/prokrutka-k-raznym-poziciam-v-scrollview-s-pomos-u-scrollviewreader-v-swiftui-2-117980459258992

Comment: @Vip_pip , оформите найденное решение в виде ответа, кому-то пригодится в будущем.